# sending email from PHP application installed on AWS EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, phpmailer, amazon-ses, sendinblue

I have a PHP application installed on the AWS EC2 server  and need SMTP to send an email over the PHP mail() function, so my question
how can I use Sendinblue SMTP or any other SMTP on Ec2

Comment: Generally, you don't. AWS wants you to use their SES service.

Comment: how to set up AWS SES?

Comment: Read the SES docs? That's not a question for SO.